# maven for wurfl 1.4

Tags: java, maven, wurfl

Is anybody else working on wurfl API version 1.4 (latest stable release). I am stuck on configuring my pom.xml for wurfl 1.4

I do not want to add wurfl manually.

ScintiaMobile says that new wurfl is hosted at their server. But the [link](http://dev.scientiamobile.com/nexus/content/repositories/public-releases/) they provide does not contain 1.4

In short my problem is I have to use **maven** and **wurfl 1.4**

Answer (score 3):

Luca Passani, ScientiaMobile's CTO here.

I know some user of the WURFL java API have requested support for Maven.

ScientiaMobile had removed Maven support in 2011, to avoid that people would inject AGPL code in their code base without fully realizing the implications of the AGPL license (strong-copyleft).

We have now introduced support for Maven for commercial licensees of the library, who can use their ScientiaMobile credentials to interact with our private Maven repo.

Details here:

http://www.scientiamobile.com/page/wurfl-adds-maven-support-for-java-programmers

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the following doesn't work in your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.wurfl</groupId>
    <artifactId>wurfl</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then what you could probably do is download the proper JAR and stick it into your organization's maven repository (Nexus, Archiva, etc) by uploading it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Download the jar from https://sourceforge.net/projects/wurfl/files/ . 
Add following in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.wurfl</groupId> 
    <artifactId>wurfl</artifactId> 
    <version>{{the.version}}</version> 
</dependency>
```

Fire the below command:

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path_to_jar/thejar.jar -DgroupId=net.sourceforge.wurfl -DartifactId=wurfl -Dversion=the.version -Dpackaging=jar

This will add the jar in your .m2 folder which can later be picked while your are building your maven project.